# Need help to make queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to figure out why my queries don't work. I want to make queries:

1) Produce a listing: custName, No_of_orders, avg_order_amt, where the middle column is the 
total number of orders for the customer and the last column is the average order amount for 
that customer. HINT: Use column aliases to get the column headings listed above to display for the output. Also, this requires two aggregate functions to be listed in the SELECT clause.

I mean I want my query to select each customer, find how many order each customer make, and average the order amount each customer has.

2) Find the customerID, customer name, orderID and total value of the order for those orders that have not been shipped. HINT: Orders that have not been shipped have a NULL value for the shipDate.

Can you help me to find the error or missing command? Here is my tables and code:

[SQL Tables](http://i1199.photobucket.com/albums/aa467/Jordan_Sanjaya/sql.png)

1.

```
Select c.cname as custName, sum(o.orderID) as No_of_orders, avg(i.price) as avg_order_amt

From Customer c, Item i

Join Order_ o

On o.customerID = c.customerID and o.itemID = i.itemID;
```

2.

```
Select c.customerID, c.cname, o.orderID

From Order_ o

Join Customer c

On c.customerID = o.customerID

Where o.orderDate = Null;
```

The result is empty set. That is not what I want. I know customerID 77777 has no order so it has to be in a set.

Comment: What errors did you get? The first one looks okay, apart from the two different kind of join notations. The second query has two pretty obvious mistakes, which should become clear if you compare the question and the solution again.

Comment: 2nd one should probably be `WHERE o.orderDate IS NULL` instead of `=`

Comment: @OGHaza Good find. But also it should be shipdate instead of orderdate.

Comment: A picture of tables? That's not how we roll.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints on what is wrong with your queries:

(1)

This query has two obvious issues.  The most obvious is that you are using aggregation functions but do not have a `group by` clause.  The second problem is the `,` in the `from` clause.  You should be using the `join` syntax in the `from` clause.  In other words, the logic in the `where` clause should be in one or more `on` clauses.

(2)

The question mentions `shipdate` but I don't see that referenced in the query.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```sql
SELECT customer_name,
       Count(*)          AS No_of_orders,
       Avg(order_amount) AS Avg_order_amount
FROM   customer_master c
       JOIN order_master o
         ON c.customer_number = o.customer_number
GROUP  BY c.customer_number;
```

Comment: There is nothing here that would help @deafprogrammer24 learn why he was not getting the results he was expecting. You might also want to answer newer and more relevant questions if you are looking to build reputation. This is 5 and a half years old. I am sure he turned in this homework long ago

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT c.customerID, c.CName , o.OrderID, sum(price) AS total_Valueof_order  
FROM OrderTable o, Customer c, Shipment s, Order_Item oi, Item i 
WHERE  s.ShipDate IS NULL 
   AND c.customerID = o.customerID
   AND o.OrderID = s.OrderID 
   AND o.OrderID = oi.OrderID 
   AND oi.ItemID = i.ItemID;
```